# Using a Swift String with NSData without NSString

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to init a Swift string (not `NSString`) with the contents of an NSData object without creating an NSString first?

I know I can use this with NSString:

```
var datastring = NSString(data data: NSData!, encoding encoding: UInt)
```

But how can I use a basic Swift String type? I thought Swift strings and NSStrings were interchangeable, do I really have to get the data out of NSData using NSString and then assign that value to a Swift string?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As of Swift 1.2 they aren't quite interchangeable, but they are convertible, so there's really no reason not to use `NSString` and its constructors when you need to. This will work fine:

```
var datastring = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
```

The `as!` is needed because `NSString(...)` can return `nil` for invalid input - if you aren't sure that the data represents a valid UTF8 string, you may wish to use the following instead to return a `String?` (aka `Optional<String>`).

```
var datastring = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String?
```

Once constructed, you can then use `datastring` just like any other Swift string, e.g.

```
var foo = datastring + "some other string"
```

Comment: when i try to parse json string. the datastring return the partial json response. but when i remove String type. It returns complete response. Ant Idea?

Comment: this gives me a runtime fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, printing of the data string just prior shows it is not nil

Comment: @naturalc, the data was probably not a valid UTF8 string. Try a different encoding, or write some code to try to detect the encoding before converting to a string.

Comment: no it was just numbers, but I went a different route

Comment: For Swift 1.2, you'll need to append  `as! String` to the end of the `NSString()` call.

Answer (score 12):

```
var buffer = [UInt8](count:data.length, repeatedValue:0)
data.getBytes(&buffer, length:data.length)
var datastring = String(bytes:buffer, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question!

Comment: This is a bit misleading. `bytes:encoding:` is from Foundation, so NSString is still being used via Objective-C bridge.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2.0 You can do something like this:-

```
import Foundation

var dataString = String(data: YourData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

In Swift 3.0 :-

```
import Foundation

var dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```